# css Onclick to show div at bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show

I built a simple page with no need to scroll down to see everything.

I have some content to show at the bottom but I don't want it to be displayed at first.

I want the user to click a phrase to be able to see this content.

The phrase would be at first positioned at the bottom of the page, then would go up a little bit once clicked to leave room to the hidden content now displaying.

This content would appear from bottom to top, like a "reverse drop-down menu" if you see what I mean.

Here is my HTML. The "click-show" h3 is the phrase that would show hidden content (four buttons) upon clicking.

```
<div class="row text-center">

        <h3 id="click-show">Click here to see the buttons.</h3>

        <hr class="spacer">

            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
            <section> <a href="#"><button>
                        <h1>Button 1</h1>
                    </button></a> </section>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
            <section> <a href="#"><button>
                        <h1>Button 2</h1>
                    </button></a> </section>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
            <section> <a href="#"><button>
                        <h1>Button 3</h1>
                    </button></a> </section>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
            <section> <a href="#"><button>
                        <h1>Button 4</h1>
                    </button></a> </section>
            </div>

        </div>
```

I'm a beginner and I really don't know if it can be done by using CSS, or other languages.

Any help/tips on this would be highly appreciated ! Thanks guys !

Comment: provide css code

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.

- `$(document).ready` - function accept callback function and trigger it when the document is loaded.
- `$('#click-show').click` - function accept callback function and trigger it when the element with id `click-show` is clicked.
- `$('div.hide-show').toggle()` if `div` element with `class="col-md-3"` hidden, show it. If it is visible, hide it.

  > I added a class name `hide-show` to the `div`'s to select particular elments only
- First load jQuery by adding the following

  `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#click-show').click(function(){
   $('div.hide-show').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.hide-show{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row text-center">

        <h3 id="click-show">Click here to see the buttons.</h3>

        <hr class="spacer">

            <div class="hide-show col-md-3 col-xs-12">
            <section> <a href="#"><button>
                        <h1>Button 1</h1>
                    </button></a> </section>
            </div>

            <div class="hide-show col-md-3 col-xs-12">
            <section> <a href="#"><button>
                        <h1>Button 2</h1>
                    </button></a> </section>
            </div>

            <div class="hide-show col-md-3 col-xs-12">
            <section> <a href="#"><button>
                        <h1>Button 3</h1>
                    </button></a> </section>
            </div>

            <div class="hide-show col-md-3 col-xs-12">
            <section> <a href="#"><button>
                        <h1>Button 4</h1>
                    </button></a> </section>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Hi Sagar, thank you very much for your help. I did exactly what you wrote but the divs that are supposed to be hidden at first are already there when page is loaded.

Comment: I have added this CSS class but unfortunately it does not show on click. I have everything set up like you wrote.
Is it working for you ?

Comment: Just as an example, I found this : https://codepen.io/nanakogawa/pen/jqXbze
This would be the exact same thing, but reversed. From bottom to top.

Comment: It is based on the alignement you have given to the tags in html